# How to remove gap as empty text between body and header in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I have Wordpress site and i try to fix some issue but right now don't see any proper way.

I have space between body and header, scanned all project but all seems good.

From chrome:

[image]

and visually it seems:

[image]

Have no clue from where I got it and where I need to search,

Please, help,

**[Edit]**

When I try to copy this empty space to Notepad++ with Incoding UTF 8 I get strange symbol (current editor can't show it)

Form Dev tool - Sources:

[image]

Comment: _View source_ can also be of help in these cases. Do you get the same as in the developer tool?

Comment: Try to open header.php file (in your template folder) with notepad++ and read this topic:
http://superuser.com/questions/292086/how-can-i-enforce-so-notepad-uses-utf-8-every-time-i-create-a-new-file

Comment: in developer tools seems as several empty rows, but my sources havn't any empty spaces. Sounds like some editor entered there illegal charecters. Do you know how to clear it?

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of UTF-8.

When I ran over all my sources followed script (that switch to UTF-8 without BOM),
everything start to work as expected.

under theme folder:

```
sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' *.php
```

for wordpres `index.php` (placed at the same level as `wp-content`)

```
 sed -i '1 s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' index.php
```

further,

I  removed `<!doctype html>` from  index.php (placed at the same level as `wp-content`) and added this tag to `index.php` of theme and `header.php`

Anyways, thanks to saosangmo for right direction